# No Marked Color in Seekbar

Tags: android

I want to remove the marked color (yellow in this case) in a seekbar.

Code:

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
    android:max="20"
    android:progress="10"
    android:secondaryProgress="0"/>
```

Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: Does my answer help? Any precisions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [View dev doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor%28int%29). SeekBar derives from View and you should try to modify either the background using `android:background` with a Shape Drawable (with solid color) in the xml definitions or programmatically change the color using setBackgroundColor.

To remove the color, you should try to set it to a pure transparent color.

I've not tested, so let us know what happen if it fails.

**Update**

You could try that:

Define a `res/drawable/white_bg.xml`

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
</shape>
```

Set the SeekBar `android:background="@drawable/white_bg"`

Give it first a try with a plain white color to see if that's a good start…

Ok, that doesn't work.

**Final update**

Ok, got it from a project of mine where I have customized a ProgessBar. Since a SeekBar derives from ProgressBar, you'll need to define a `res/drawable/seekbar_bg.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
      <corners android:radius="5dip" />
      <gradient
          android:startColor="#ff9d9e9d"
          android:centerColor="#ff5a5d5a"
          android:centerY="0.75"
          android:endColor="#ff747674"
          android:angle="270"/>
    </shape>
  </item>

  <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
      <shape>
        <corners android:radius="5dip" />
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
      </shape>
    </clip>
  </item>

</layer-list>
```

similarly that the `platforms/android-8/data/res/drawable/progress_horizontal.xml` file (android-8 is an example) and define the`android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_bg"` attribute for your SeekBar xml definition.

I assumed there that the `@android:id/secondaryProgress` item need not to be defined in the [Layer List](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList) for a SeekBar but it should be verified…

You could as well redefine [the thumb symbol selector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html#attr_android%3athumb) by declaring a local selector inspired by `platforms/android-8/data/res/drawable/seek_thumb.xml`.

Interesting, I have learned a lot with this one since I never used a SeekBar, thanks! ;)

My apologies for the trial/error approach and the multiple updates…

Comment: i tried sb.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); --> nothing changed

Comment: @test123123 Ok, that was not so simple but I edited my answer and it works, I let you redefine the thumb symbol if need be by yourself…